# WFP View not updating when object properties change with INotifyPropertyChanged implemented via Fody

Tags: wpf, binding, fody

I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find a solution to this.  The object/class that I have bound to a WPF form shows the object properties fine on the first creation of the object.  Now however, if I change any of the properties in the object, the form will not update with the changes. I can force the form to show the changes if I alter the XAML properties in a debug session though... odd.  This was working previously.  The one thing I changed was that I moved the object class to another project and am referencing it rather than the class being located in the same project.  I'm stumped.
Any help would be great!

Comment: revert things you changed and it will work as it was working previously

Comment: hmm...I would like to keep these changes as it provides a bit more organization for the overall project...just trying to get to the cause of the issue.  It doesn't make much sense that the form draws fine on the first go but won't update with property changes anymore.

Comment: With help here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56048565/error-fody-no-weavers-found-add-the-desired-weavers-via-their-nuget-package
I got it...the fody xml config wasn't set to include the PropertyChanged package.

Answer (score 0):

When I installed Fody on the referenced project the Fody weavers XML did not update.  I added the PropertyChanged directive manually to the file and all is good. BTW Fody is amazing!

[Error Fody: No weavers found. Add the desired weavers via their nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56048565/error-fody-no-weavers-found-add-the-desired-weavers-via-their-nuget-package)